# inner join with allowing user to choose between search type do not work

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

i have a search  page tat allow users to search using  search by governorate or district or village

if the user choose by governorate the browser display right answers

but if the user choose governorate and district the system do change it display the same result

governorate

- governorate_id
- governorate_name
  district
- district_id
- district_name
- governorate_id

village

- id
- village_name
- district_id

members 
user_id

- governorate_id
- district_id
- village_id

i want when the user choose one of the types or all of the the system must display the users list related to the selection not all users

## code:

```
    $errorMSG = "";
    $outputlist = "";
    //**********search by locationn***************************************//
    if(isset($_POST['listbyq']))
    {    
    //********************by governorate**************************************//
       if($_POST['listbyq']=="by_gov")
       {
           $bygov = $_POST['governorate'];
           @ $bydist = $_POST['district'];
           @ $byvillage = $_POST['village'];
            echo $bygov;
            echo $bydist;
            echo $byvillage;


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, 
s.specialization_name,
g.governorate_name,
d.district_name,
v.village_name 
      FROM members u
                   INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                    ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id
                    INNER JOIN governorate g
                    ON u.governorate = g.governorate_id
                    INNER JOIN districts d
                    ON u.district = d.district_id
                    INNER JOIN village v
                    ON u.village = v.id
                   where ($bygov = '' or governorate = '$bygov') and
                         ($bydist = '' or district = '$bydist') and
                         ($byvillage = '' or village = '$byvillage')")
                         or die(mysql_error());
           $num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
           if($num_row > 0 )
           {
               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
               {
                  $row_id = $row['user_id'];
                  $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
                  $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
                  $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
                  $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];
                  $row_spec = $row['specialization_name'];
                  $row_gov = $row['governorate_name'];
                  $row_dist = $row['district_name'];
                  $row_village = $row['village_name'];

                    ////***********for the upload image*************************//
             $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
             $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
             if(file_exists($check_pic))
             {
                 $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
             }
             else
             {
                 $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
             }

              $outputlist.='
         <table width="100%">
                     <tr>
                        <td width="23%" rowspan="5"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href =              "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                        <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                        <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                          <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Job:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_spec.'</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Location:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_gov.'__'.$row_dist.'__'.$row_village.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <hr />
                ';

               }
           }

       }
       else
       {
           $errorMSG = "No member within this selected governorate";
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues is your `where` clause:

```
   WHERE governorate = '$bygov' OR district = '$bydist' OR village = '$byvillage'"
```

These are connected by `or` not `and`.

Presumably, when someone selects governate and district, you want the district *and* the governate, not the district *or* the governate.  One approach is to code the `where` clause like:

```
where ($bygov = '' or governorate = '$bygov') and
      ($bydist = '' or district = '$bydist') and
      ($byvillage = '' or village = '$byvillage')
```

Another approach is to use custom code at the application level to customize the `where` clause for each case, something like:

```
$where = '';
if ($bygov != '') {$where = $where." governate = '$bygov' and "}
if ($bydist != '') {$where = $where." district = '$bydist' and"}
if ($byvillage != '') {$where = $where." village = '$byvillage' and"}
$where = $where." 1=1"
```

Comment: id tried the first way but the browser display this error :   **20You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '' or village = )' at line 17**

Comment: @user2396708 . . . It was missing single quotes.

Comment: i will edit my question see the query but the browser still display the error

Comment: @user2396708 . . . What value does each variable take when there is no input?  Is it NULL or an empty string?